# Scala recursion, overflow

Tags: scala, recursion, stack-overflow

Here are 2 functions:

```
def Foo1(s: ((BigInt, Long) => Long)
=> ((BigInt, Long) => Long)): (BigInt, Long) => Long = s(Foo1(s))

def Foo2(s: (=> (BigInt, Long) => Long)
=> ((BigInt, Long) => Long)): (BigInt, Long) => Long = s(Foo2(s))
```

When they are called with the following parameters:

```
Foo1(rec => (x, s) =>
          if (x == 1) s
          else rec(if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else 3 * x + 1, s + 1))(56, 0)    
Foo2(rec => (x, s) =>
          if (x == 1) s
          else rec(if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else 3 * x + 1, s + 1))(56, 0)
```

The first causes stack overflow, and the second executes normally.

Also, what does this expression mean: `(=> (BigInt, Long) => Long)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature `(=> (BigInt, Long) => Long)` indicates a call-by-name parameter, and is the key to understanding why `Foo2` does not overflow the stack.

The way to understand a function in Scala is to substitute the arguments into the definition of the function. You then repeat the substitution as you evaluate the arguments. We also have to recognize that `s` is used in two different places, one as the parameter to the `Foo` function, and one as the parameter in the unnamed function passed to `Foo`.

Evaluating the first function invocation binds the parameter `s` to

`rec => (x, s) =>
          if (x == 1) s
          else rec(if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else 3 * x + 1, s + 1)`

which turns `rec` into a recursive function of two arguments, a `BigInt` and a `Long`.

Then you evaluate `Foo1`, substituting the expression value of `s`, the outer one, into `s( Foo1( s ) )`. This yields:

```
( rec => (x, s) =>
          if (x == 1) s
          else rec(if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else 3 * x + 1, s + 1) ) ( Foo1( rec => (x, s) =>
          if (x == 1) s
          else rec(if (x % 2 == 0) x / 2 else 3 * x + 1, s + 1) )
```

You then need to evaluate `Foo1`, passing it the function. This will go on recursively until you run out of stack space.

`Foo2`, on the other hand, uses call-by-name syntax instead of call-by-value, so it does not need to do the second stage of the evaluation until the parameters, `(56, 0)`, are actually bound.